# How to detect stop points from GPS dataset in R/Python

Tags: python, r, gps, dbscan, scikits

I noticed that in `Python` we have  `detection.stops` function in `scikit-mobility` to detect stop points in GPS dataset.

[scikit-mobility](https://github.com/scikit-mobility/scikit-mobility)

Does `R` have a similar package/function to do the task?